# Как получить message.text или предложите как лучше сделать python telebot?

Tags: python, telebot

Я пишу код телеграм бота в python

Я хочу после того как пользователь написал текст (допустим картошка), в свойстах стоит inlinekeyboard кнопки (допустим почистить и помыть) и если пользователь нажимает одну из них бот запоминает предыдущее сообщение и переходит выполнять функцию исходя из данных отправленных боту.

Сейчас отправлю пример:

```
elif message.text.lower() == 'овощи или фрукты':
        msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, text="отправьте фрукт или овощ",
        parse_mode='markdown')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, ovoshifructs)

def ovoshifructs(message):
        bot.reply_to(message, 
                     text= "Что хотите сделать?",
                     parse_mode='Markdown',
                     reply_markup=menu.choosecountry) #тут 2 Inline кнопки почистить или помыть
```

Затем бот принимает данные в @bot.callback_query_handler

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def handler_call(call):
        chat_id = call.message.chat.id
        message_id = call.message.message_id

        if call.data == 'pochistit':
            dict = func.savetext(chat_id) #class savetext
            savetext_dict[chat_id] = dict #dict savetext

            dict = savetext_dict[chat_id]
            msg = dict.text = message.text #error
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, handle_fructs_ovochi)
```

И вот под конец оно не знает что такое message.text. Возможно у вас есть варианты как можно сократить код, а не перекидывать каждый раз или сделать его компактнее. А в целом проблема была в том что в call нет message то-есть сохранить отправленный текст после нажатия inline кнопки нельзя

То-есть мне надо сохранить слово картошка и запустить ту функцию которую юзер выбрал на inline кнопках

Comment: Ну т.е. вы объявили данные в одном методе а получить пытаетесь в совершенно другом никак не передавая данные? очень подозреваю что вы просто пропустили call (вот так call.message.text) или делаете дикую дичь которую я описал в первом предложении.

Comment: ааа, спасибо большое за подсказку call. Всё равно какая-то каша получается у меня тут

Comment: Какая именно? в тексте находится совсем не то что вы хотите?

Comment: Я не до конца разобрался как сохранить временно отправленный текст картошка как переменную чтобы отправить это всё в функцию handle_fructs_ovochi

Comment: Самый простой, но неверный, способ это глобальная переменная, вам же нужно реализовать по сути statemachine(а вот это уже верный подход к вашей задаче), еле вспомнил как по русски:  конечный автомат.

Comment: Тут такая проблема что я думаю это можно решить без этого, после того как я нажал почистить, оно закидывает в функцию чистки, НО у него нет сообщения что именно чистить, в нашем случае это картошка, функция ожидает повторной отправки сообщения и только тогда она заработает, а мне нужно чтобы сразу она начала работать

Comment: Ответ в моем предыдущем комментарии, вам нужно где-то хранить "текущее состояние" это можно сделать костылем в виде глобальной переменной, или реализовав конечный автомат.

Comment: как пример https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Comment: Спасибо, я это уловил но функция стопится почему-то, как это исправить?

Comment: После bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, handle_fructs_ovochi) оно перекидывает на следующую функцию но ожидает сообщение, хотя я его сохранил, то-есть боту не нужно повторно его писать, а он стопится и ждёт это сообщение в самом телеграмме

Comment: что можно сделать ?

Comment: Я так понимаю я должен передать messageid или что-то в этом роде

Comment: В общем решил это благодаря вашему способу, но без register_next_handler а напрямую запустил и указал аргумент message